# Is there a concise syntax in R for saying "define if not already defined?"

Tags: r

If I want to assign a variable only if it is not undefined, is this the most concise way to do it, or is there a shorter syntax to represent the idea?

```
if (!exists('t')) t = 1
```

For example, in `C#`, one can write

```
int y = x ?? -1;
```

To express the idea that `y` should be assigned to `x` unless `x` is null.

Comment: whats wrong with just `t = 1` . It will assign value of 1 to t or overwrite it's value by 1

Comment: @geektrader, the point is that if `t` is already assigned, I do not want to assign it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could stitch together your own infix operator:

```
`%<-%`  <- function(x,y){
   nm <- as.character(substitute(x))
   if (!exists(nm,where = parent.frame())){
     assign(x=nm,value=y,envir = parent.frame())
     return(TRUE)
   }else{
     return(FALSE)
   }
 }

> x <- 2 
> x %<-% 5
[1] FALSE
> x
[1] 2
> y %<-% 10
[1] TRUE
> y
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to check whether a vector is null or not is using the length function. This may not be relevant to your specific question though.

```
> t<-NULL
> length(t)
[1] 0
> t<-1
> length(t)
[1] 1
```