# Matlab: assign variable only if not already existing?

Tags: matlab

This is the matlab equivalent to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647914/is-there-a-concise-syntax-in-r-for-saying-define-if-not-already-defined).  Essentially, I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid explicitly writing the `exists` check for a variable before assigning it.

Comment: so actually you want a constant? [There are some workarounds](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98309) but I'd assume the use of `exist` is the most convenient way. Thats the purpose of this function.

Comment: I want a variable that is assigned once per matlab session. It might be expensive to compute it, or it may depend on some value that changes later on. I basically do not want it recomputed the second time a script is run.

Comment: If you look at the answer to the question I linked, it offers a nice hack to provide the `%<-%` syntactic sugar around `exists` in `R`. I wonder if something similar is possible in matlab.

Comment: So actually you're just looking for a shorter representation of the `exist` functionality, right? [Have a look here: How to create custom operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224666/any-way-to-accomplish-i-in-matlab)

Comment: Correct. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
persistent varname
if isempty(varname)
    varname=heavyComputation()
end
```

This will only recompute varname at startup and after each `clear fun` and `clear all`.

Answer (score 2):

Why avoid [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html)? This is exactly what it is for:

```
if ~exist('t', 'var')
   t = 1
end
```

For your specific use case, if you don't want a certain variable to be recalculated, [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) it into a MAT-file and check for its existence before recalculating. For example, if you are calculating `A`, then you can do something along the lines of:

```
if exist('mycalcs.mat', 'file')
   load('mycalcs.mat', 'A')      %// Load precalculated A
else
   A = do_some_calculations();   %// Calculate A
   save('mycalcs.mat', 'A');     %// Save it to a workspace file
end
```

This allows you to rerun the script without repeating calculations, even after clearing the variable in question or closing MATLAB altogether.

Comment: Is there a reason for downvoting this answer?

Comment: If you never want to overwrite a variable, the `persistent` solution seems practical. However if you don't want to overwrite it in part of your code, this should be a good solution.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I'm not really following you.

Comment: Perhaps you can state the advantages/disadvantages compared to the solution by @user2987828. My thought is that they are both suitable for different situations. (Note that my comment is not related to the downvote)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin `persistent` resembles the `static` keyword in C. I'm not sure where the OP wants to perform his calculation, but it seems that using `exist` is more robust here (especially if the calculation can yield an empty matrix).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the syntax `who(variable_name)` to check if the variable exists in the workspace as shown here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html

Comment: To automate this, you'll have to test the output of `who`. Isn't `exist` superior in this case?